# How enable operating correctly traversal keys UP ARROW and DOWN ARROW in Nebula SWT widget DateChooserCombo?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

When I try
implement TraverseListener and run program then key AP ARROW (or DOWN
ARROW) stop on button (button for popup calendar, default left side) in
DateChooserCombo widget. How implement this listener with key UP ARROW
and DOWN ARROW working identical as key TAB? Example:

```
DateChooserCombo dateChooserCombo = new DateChooserCombo(shell, SWT.NONE);
dateChooserCombo.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
  public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
        if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN || e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_DOWN) {
            e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT;
           } else if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_UP) {
            e.detail = SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS;               
            }
        e.doit = true;
        }
        });
```